# Python message box showing without stopping script

Tags: python, loops, messagebox

I have an script that create numbers randomly, between 5 and 55, in a infinite loop. My goal is to show a message box when the number 55 is created. I have try easygui, tkinter, ctypes,... and I have been able to create the message box, but when this box appears the loop stops and it doesn't continue untill the user clicks de OK button. Is there a way to show a message box without stopping the script?

I have been looking for information in forums but I haven't found someone with this problem, so I hope someone can help me.

This is the part of the code with the loop:

```
 def contador():
  for x in range(1):
    aleatorio = random.randint(1,11)*5
    if aleatorio ==55:
        estado = "Red"
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"Error", u"Error", 0)
    elif aleatorio >=30:
        estado = "Red"

    else:
        estado = "Green"

    global t 
 t = threading.Timer(15.0, contador)
 t.start()

t = threading.Timer(15.0, contador)
t.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

messageboxes in most cases (tkinter, gtk, winapi) are modal windows. You can create your own dialog or you can use threads.

```
import random
from Tkinter import Tk

def show_error(text):
    top = Toplevel(root)
    Label(top, text=text).pack()
    Button(top, text="OK", command=top.destroy).pack(pady=5)

def contador():
    for x in range(100):
        aleatorio = random.randint(1,11)*5
        if aleatorio == 55:
            estado = "Red"
            show_error('Some error occurred: %s' % x)
        elif aleatorio >=30:
            estado = "Red"
        else:
            estado = "Green"

contador()
```